# How do I put the UIView subclass into the interface?

Tags: objective-c

Matt, I read the part of your book about implementation and interface and I was wondering if this was the correct way to put the UIView subclass into the interface.

```
@interface PDC : UIView
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@end
```

Comment: Who's "Matt" and what book did they write? Stack Overflow is a general question and answer site, not a specific person's blog or personal website.

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are already defined in the base class, UIView, so you don't need to re-declare them in the subclass's interface.  You can override them in the implementation file to add your subclass's customized behavior, and you will be able to call those methods from other classes because they are already public in UIView.

It is also good to follow the naming convention of adding the suffix 'View' if it is a subclass of a UIView.

```
@interface PDCView : UIView
@end


@implementation PDCView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
         // Your custom initialization here
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Your logic here
}

@end
```